# select value from two tables where years are the same

Tags: mysql

I am selecting data from two tables where years are the same. The value selected from `table B` should show its items even when values in `table c` do not match.

```
table a
|   ItmID   |   NAME    |
|   001     |   book    |       
|   002     |   pencil  |


table b
|   ItmID   |   Amount      |   Year    |
|   001     |   100.00      |   2010    |
|   001     |   150.00      |   2011    |


table c
|   ItmID   |   interest    |   Year    |
|   001     |   10.00       |   2010    |
```

In the above tables, I would like to  query out just the Amount and the interest value of the book for the year 2010.

```
expected results
|   NAME    |   Amount  |   interest    |   Year    |
|   book    |   100.00  |   10.00       |   2010    |
```

This is what i have tried so far

```
SELECT  
    a.NAME,
    b.Amount,
    c.interest
FROM
    table a
LEFT JOIN
    table b
ON
    a.ItmID=b.ItmID
LEFT JOIN
    table c
ON
    a.ItmID=c.ItmID
where
    b.year=2010 and c.year=2010
```

This is able to give me the values correctly, but when there are no values in `table c` the query runs empty.

For instance if i want to query out just the Amount and the interest value of the book for the year 2011.
The query will run empty because there is no interest value for year 2011.

Please is there something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the where conditions to your on clause:

```
SELECT  
    a.NAME,
    b.Amount,
    c.interest
FROM
    table a
LEFT JOIN
    table b
ON
    a.ItmID=b.ItmID and     b.year=2010 
LEFT JOIN
    table c
ON
    a.ItmID=c.ItmID and c.year=2010
```

So if you work with where clause you have to check if c.year is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @a table (itemid int,name varchar(10)) 
    insert into @a(itemid,name)values (001,'book')
    insert into @a(itemid,name)values (002,'pencil')

    declare @b table (itemid int,amt money,years varchar(5)) 
    insert into @b(itemid,amt,years)values (001,100.00,2010)
    insert into @b(itemid,amt,years)values (001,150.00,2011)

    declare @c table (itemid int,interest money,years varchar(5)) 
    insert into @c(itemid,interest,years)values (001,10.00,2010)

select distinct top 1 name,amt,interest,c.years from @a a,@b,@c c
```

Comment: Think top 1 is `sql-server` syntax not `mysql` as op ask for.

Comment: select  name,amt,interest,c.years from @a a,@b,@c c   LIMIT 1 ...may be it works

Answer (score 0):

If you want it where tableC's year matches tableB's year. Not just specifically for 2010. Also you said you want all values of tableB even if there is no value for tableC. Your left join will do that for you.

```
SELECT  
    a.NAME,
    b.Amount,
    c.interest
FROM
    table a
LEFT JOIN
    table b
ON
    a.ItmID=b.ItmID
LEFT JOIN
    table c
ON
    a.ItmID=c.ItmID
    AND
    b.year=c.year
```